Perturbative expansion of eigenstate obeying Periodic Boundary Condition
I have an eigenstate as,
$$e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle$$ with Hamiltonian $$\hat{H}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^N (p_i - \hbar \alpha)^2 + V$$
$|\psi_0\rangle$ is the many body ground eigenstate obeying periodic boundary condition, $\hat{X}=\sum_{i=1}^N \hat{x_i}$ and L is the periodicity of the 1D lattice.
I expanded the Hamiltonian to get the perturbing Hamiltonian and then tried to apply perturbation expansion to get
$$ e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle \approx e^{i \gamma_L} \left(|\psi_0\rangle -   \frac{2\pi \hbar}{mL}   \sum_{j\neq 0} |\psi_j\rangle \frac{\langle \psi_j |\hat{P}| \psi_0\rangle}{E_0 -E_j} \right)$$
$|\psi_j\rangle$ is the Eigenstate of $\hat{H}(0)$ and $\hat{P}= \sum_{i=1}^N p_i$ is the momentum operator.
After doing the perturbative expansion I am getting all the terms except for pre factor $e^{i \gamma_L}$, How can this be achieved and What is the significance of this pre-factor here?
Is it related to Berry Phase? For reference see equation 7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9709306
